# How to mount a physical hard drive in VMware Workstation Pro 15 as a guest in a Linux host?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

**Background:** I've got a Linux computer with multiple hard drives. I run Ubuntu 19.04 as my daily driver, and VMware Workstation Pro 15.

**Example 1:** I want to be able to install Windows on a second internal drive, so I can dual boot into it, but also be able to run it as a guest OS. I have Windows to run things like Fusion 360 and Tableau (things that don't work reliably in Wine).

**Example 2:** I'd like to be able to grab a physical hard drive out of a machine and from my host OS, run the guest from that hard drive as a guest VM on my host. The guest OS might be Linux, Windows or any other guest VMware Workstation supports. Then I'd like to be able to put that HD back in the original machine and have it work. I realize it'll make changes to the guest HD. This isn't for forensics or anything, so it's ok if the data on the guest OS drive changes.

Also, I fully expect when I switch how it boots to prompt me for different drivers to be installed/configured.

Is scenario possible with VMware Workstation 15 Pro? I've done quite a bit of searching the Internet and VMware's site, but can't find a clear answer.

Here's a KB article on how to *convert* a hard drive to a VM (https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2005129), but that's not what I want. I want to be able to go back and forth between virtualized and native on the same OS and disk.

Comment: Did you look at this: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2046678